# How to delete all files in folder from shared excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have one shared excel file and i want to make a button in excel file on that shared excel file that will delete all the files from folder abc.
Below code is working fine but only issue is it deleting when file is shared.

```
Sub delete()
    Kill "\Desktop\Tracking\*.xl*"
End Sub
```

is it possible to delete the files in folder from shared excel file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure I'm getting what your asking... Is this shared excel file going to delete files off of each persons C drive? If so maybe the following will help.

```
Kill "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\Tracking\*.xl*"
```